# Pytest cannot test multiple cases with @pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, django, pytest-django, parametrized-testing, pytest-factoryboy

I defined `UserFactory` class in `tests/factories.py` as shown below following [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions). *I use [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [pytest-factoryboy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-factoryboy) in Django:

```py
# "tests/factories.py"

import factory

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

And, I defined `test_user_instance()` with [@pytest.mark.parametrize()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) to test 4 users as shown below:

```py
# "tests/test_ex1.py"

import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "username, email",
    {
        ("John", "test@test.com"), # Here
        ("John", "test@test.com"), # Here
        ("John", "test@test.com"), # Here
        ("John", "test@test.com")  # Here
    }
)
def test_user_instance(
    db, user_factory, username, email
):
    user_factory(
        username=username,
        email=email
    )

    item = User.objects.all().count()
    assert item == True
```

But, only one user was tested as shown below:

```
$ pytest -q
.                                [100%]
1 passed in 0.65s
```

So, how can I test 4 tests?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as typo. You can't repeat `("John", "test@test.com")` (a tuple/hashable) 4 times inside a set and expect to get all 4 back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[]` instead of `{}` to surround 4 users as shown below:

```py
# "tests/test_ex1.py"

import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "username, email",
    [ # <- Here
        ("John", "test@test.com"),
        ("John", "test@test.com"),
        ("John", "test@test.com"),
        ("John", "test@test.com")
    ] # <- Here
)
def test_user_instance(
    db, user_factory, username, email
):
    user_factory(
        username=username,
        email=email
    )

    item = User.objects.all().count()
    assert item == True
```

Then, you can test 4 users as shown below:

```
$ pytest -q
....                             [100%]
4 passed in 0.68s
```